# Error on chromecast receiver app PLAYBACK/104

Tags: html, html5-video, chromecast

I have an html5 receiver app that I'm writing for a client who already has a sender app. On playing a video for a second time, I get this error:

> [cast.player.api.Player] error
>
> [cast.player.api.Host] error: cast.player.api.ErrorCode.PLAYBACK/104

I can't tell if this error is coming from my implementation of the media library or from the sender app. Any guidance?

Answer (score 2):

You can see in the [Media Player Library Error Codes](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/mpl_error_codes#media-player-library-error-codes) that this error means "The media element fired MediaError.MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED error." The suggested solution from the docs is to Validate developer data segment, ensure the codecs are included in [Cast supported formats](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media). You can read more about the cast.player.api [here](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/player/cast.player.api#.ErrorCode#.PLAYBACK).

Comment: So, that's very weird because the source is the exact same both times. I only get this error the second time I play it.

Comment: @MorganLaVigne For what it's worth, I've found that the Chromecast will cache the HLS manifest for a bit.  I had an issue where when re-casting shortly after ending the first playback, that it would be referencing segments that were deleted as they were well into the past.